# Update query with expressJS/MySQL

Tags: express

I have a probleme with my update query.
It works when i create or get a user..

```
update(id) {
    return http.put(`/users/${id}`);
  }
```

//

```
router.put("/:id", users.update);
```

//

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    id: req.params.id,
     name:req.body.name,
   ...
    
  };

  

    User.update({where: {
      id: req.params.id
    }} , user).then(
    () => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Thing updated successfully!'
      });
    }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        message:user,
        error: error
      });
    }
  ); 
  
};
```

//
Postman

PUT http://localhost:8081/api/users/2

BODY
{

"name": "h2@gmail.com"

}

{
"message": {
"id": "2",
"name": "h2@gmail.com"
},
"error": {
"generatedMessage": false,
"code": "ERR_ASSERTION",
"expected": true,
"operator": "=="
}
}

Comment: try this User.update(user,{where: {
      id: req.params.id
    }})

Comment: Ok I am posting it as answer pls do accept it

Answer (score 1):

According to sequilize docs, the first parameter should be the object to update and second parameter to be the condition.

```
User.update(user,{where: { id: req.params.id }})
```